# removing a part of url using Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: regex, nginx

I have an Nginx rewrite rule that is supposed to remove **abc** from

```
https://mypage.com/abc/home/filename?a=123&b=/a123/b123
```

and return

```
https://mypage.com/home/filename?a=123&b=/a123/b123
```

my rule is:

```
rewrite /abc/home/(.*)$ /home/$1 permanent;
location ~ ^/home(/.*)$ {
  root /my/path/to/app;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
}
```

instead of that, it is changing the url to:

```
https://mypage.com/home/abc/
```

it basically **replaced** *home* and *abc* and completely **removed** *filename*.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I think nginx is not matching the **?** character. Maybe because Nginx treats **?** differently?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shall work:

```
location ~ ^/abc/home/filename {
    rewrite ^/abc(/.*)$ /home/filename permanent;
}
```

It shall clean `abc` and return everything afterwards.

Comment: filename may be followed by other arguments as I mentioned earlier:
https://mypage.com/home/filename?a=123&b=/a123/b123